# How to pass a quoted string plus other values as a single parameter to another function

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, quotes

If a have a variable whose value can both feature spaces or not like this one:

```
set myvar=value1 "my value 2" value3
```

How can I provide this parameter to another function as a whole parameter without it being broken into other parameters.

```
CALL: MYFUNC other.param1 myvar other.param2

:MYFUNC
set other.param1=%1
set myvar=%2       
set other.param1=%3
```

When faced with similar problems I used to quote the parameter but that approach does not work anymore because the parameter itself already has quotes inside.

Comment: Pass the variable name as a reference instead of the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the variable name as a reference instead of the variable contents.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET myvar=value1 "my value 2" value3
CALL :MYFUNC other.param1 myvar other.param2
GOTO :EOF

:MYFUNC
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set other.param1=%1
set myfuncvar=!%2!       
set other.param3=%3
echo %other.param1%
echo %myfuncvar%
echo %other.param3%
endlocal
pause
```